# How to retrieve a retrofit result in a repository?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-room, repository-pattern, android-livedata

According to google, Repository should be the single source of truth provider for a piece of data but when using retrofit, we enqueue the request which is async, so I am using Livedata to observe the changes to result of the request. But we cannot observe livedata in a repository. So how do I listen to the result in repository so that when results are fetched, I can reflect the changes in the repo.

Below are the codes of my Datasource and Repository

```
// repository functions to fetch masters and save them to database
fun getAllMaster(): LiveData<List<Master>> {

        // save response from datasource to database
        // call
        
        // I want to observe the changes to request here
        val masters = MasterHook().fetchMasters()
        executor.execute{
            for(master in masters){
                masterDao.insertMaster(master)
            }
        }

        return masterDao.getAllMasters()
    }
```

```
// Datasource function
 fun fetchMasters():LiveData<List<Master>>{
        val responseLiveData= MutableLiveData<List<Master>>()
        val masterRequest: Call<List<Master>> = dashboardApi.fetchMasters(token =
        "Bearer tokenHere")

        masterRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Master>>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Master>>,
                response: Response<List<Master>>
            ) {
                Log.d("Dashboard API", "Response Received")
                val masters = response.body()
                if (masters != null) {
                    Log.d("Fetcher", masters.toString())
                    responseLiveData.value = masters
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Master>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Dashboard API","Failed to fetch masters",t)
            }

        })

        return responseLiveData
    }
```

Comment: you can try using suspend function and coroutines. That will keep your livedata at viewmodel and not repository layer.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach there is using the suspend function and coroutines as follows

1. Create a suspend function to request data

```kotlin
     @GET
    suspend fun fetMasters(@Query("token") apiToken : String) : Response<Master>
```

2. To save data coming from the Rest API to a local database (Room) there are several ways to achieve this task, you can use Paging Library (version is simplified one) you can use MediatorLiveData or even using Work Library for simplicity in the repository you can fetch data and insert to the Room db directly as follows

```kotlin
     class ApiHelper( private val masterService: MasterService) {
        suspend fun getMaster() : Response<Master> = 
            masterService.fetchMasters(tokenKey)
        }
 

     class Repository(private val apiHelper : ApiHelper) {

      suspend fun callDataFromDb() 
      CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        
        val masterResponse = apiHelper.getMaster
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                if (masterResponse.isSuccessful) {
                    masterDao.insertMaster(masterResponse.body)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: ${masterResponseresponse.code()}")
                }
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Ooops: Something else went wrong")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

3. In the ViewModel you call the method callDataFromDb as follows

```kotlin
      class MasterViewModel(val repository) : ViewModel {
           init {
           calldata()
         }
        fun calldata() = viewModelScope.launch {
          repository.callDataFromDb
         }
      }
```

From there you can functions that retrieve data from the database.